# Choosing an import format: AAF vs OMF

Tags: video, software, editing

I am developing a video rendering application. I would like to import editing projects from non-linear video editing application like Avid or FCP.

Which format should I start with, AAF or OMF? What would be the pros and cons of either?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AAF is the newer and more complete framework.  It is the successor to OMF, which still lives on but mostly because of legacy applications.

Note that [Automatic Duck](http://www.automaticduck.com/products/) makes a line of highly-regarded tools that help with import and export of these interchange formats and have recently been made available for free.